# How to analyse data collected in different ways

Tags: regression, anova, case-control-study

Let's say I collect some quantitative case-control data. First thing that pops into my mind is using a t-test to see if these two groups differ.

Let's say some more data is collected, but it's just a bit different (a different experiment collected it, or machine that collects data has some variability or whatever). What are my options on analyzing this data?

First thing that pops into my mind is regression or ANOVA (using indicator variables) as a comment points out below :

$E[Y] = \beta_0 + \beta_1*CASE + \beta_2*BATCH$

where $BATCH$ represents in which 'batch' the data was collected (or which experimenter, or machine, etc). Are there better ways to do this analysis? I know this is quite an open-ended question but I just wanted to see what else is available.

Comment: What you want sounds more like analysis of variance. Running a regression on case and batch identifiers needs to be recast using indicator variables. That is still regression, but doing it as analysis of variance is likely to be a little easier for you.